# How to put back unity lens?

Tags: apt

I did

```
sudo apt-get autoremove unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos unity-lens-gwibber unity-lens-shopping unity-lens-video
```

How can I put it back please - Using Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos unity-lens-gwibber unity-lens-shopping unity-lens-video
```

That should sort your problem out :-) - this piece of text is just due to StackExchange minimum text limit on an answer. If you have any other problems, post a comment.